# How can I keep an app running when Extreme Battery Saver is on?

Tags: applications, settings, battery-saver

I'm using a Google Pixel 5 with Android 13 Beta. It has an Extreme Battery Saver mode which the system will ask me to turn on if the battery level goes under 10%. After it is enabled, most apps will be paused, except for a few essential apps: Messages, Phone, Clock, etc.

When I tap on a paused app's icon, for example, YouTube Music, it will show the prompt:

[image]

> **App paused by Extreme Battery Saver**
>
> Keeping [app's name] paused extends your device's battery life.
>
> You can unpause it temporarily or set essential apps to always work in Settings.
>
> <kbd>Unpause temporarily</kbd> <kbd>OK</kbd>

I tried to change the option to Unrestricted in Settings > Apps > All Apps > YouTube Music > Battery > Optimized, but it doesn't give the desired effect.

What is the right thing to do to allow custom apps to always work in Settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, use the path Settings> Battery Saver> Extreme Battery Saver> Essential Apps and check the box next to the app you want unrestricted.

To use an app while Extreme Battery Saver is on, tap the app that is paused, on the message that shows, tap Unpause temporarily. After a few minutes, you’ll get a notification to pause.
To let the app pause again, do nothing or swipe away the notification.
To stay unpaused longer, tap Wait until.
You can also go into Extreme Battery Saver, tap essential apps, and select that app to be unrestricted when the battery saver is on.